# JSON index adds to itself instead of starting by 0 on reload

Tags: javascript, json, function, appcelerator

I am sure this must have an easy solution, but I can't seem to get it right.
When I reload a function in javascript that reads data from an external JSON like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

the json.index works fine the first time with an index starting on 0, but when I reload the function (or call again the function) then the index is (0+json.length) and thats a problem for me because I need the index in order to get the correct data in another window.
Any clue on how to get the json start with an index = 0 each time I run the function?

Thanks a LOT!

update: Here is the function I am re-calling. Code has been cropped for simplicity. Also its worth noting that this is an Appcelerator project.

```
A2B.createView = function(tipo) {

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open("GET","http://localhost.com");
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        if (!json) { 
            Titanium.API.info('Error - Null return!'); 
            return;
        }
         var myAnnotations = new Array();
         var json = json.all;
         var pos;


        if (tipo==1){

        for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){
          // this adds some markers to a map
          myAnnotations.push(dbMarker);

        }
        }
        else {
            for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){
         myAnnotations.push(dbMarker);
        }           
        }


        A2B.mapview.annotations = myAnnotations;


    };
    xhr.send();


    A2B.win.add(A2B.mapview);

    // map view click event listener
    A2B.mapview.addEventListener('click', function(json) {
        if (json.clicksource == 'rightButton') {
                var w2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    title:'XXX', 
                    url:'eachevent.js', 
                    backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'
});
                w2.stringProp1 = ''+json.index+'';
//the value of json.index is the one that it keeps adding to itself when I call the function
                w2.myFunc = function()
                {
                    return 'myFunc was called';
                };
                w2.open({modal:true});
                };

    });

    });
};
```

Comment: What is responseText? how does it change across reloads?

Comment: How about showing that function and the response (the JSON) you get? The line of code you posted does not tell us anything.

Comment: I have added the function now, hope it helps.

Comment: The function still doesn't make much sense, who's passing json into A2B.mapview's click handler? Your code formatting is still really crappy, I tried to fix it for you but you have all kinds of mismatching brackets

Comment: Hello Juan, please take into account that this is an appcelerator project, A2B is being called in another "view". The way to call it is like this A2B.createView();. Regarding the brackets it may happen when I cropped the code to add it here, I will recheck it now.

Comment: are you logging responseText each time?

Comment: what are u using the variable name json all over the place? it makes it difficult to follow your code and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reusing/caching the same XmlHttpRequest object each time? i.e.

```
this.xmlHttpRequest =  new XmlHttpRequest()
```

If so, it could be an issue of the multiple responseTexts being concatenated together, creating a longer and longer parsed *json* variable.  Could you show us the code please?

Comment: I've never heard of responseTexts being concatenated together... you saying you have?

Comment: yes.  In a project I was making a while ago, I was creating an API wrapper for communicating with a WebDVR webservice.  Upon creating an instance of my API class/object, when an request needed to be made, I was storing the XmlHttpRequest object as _this.XmlHttpRequest_ (having created it in an init function upon the instantiation).  After making a second call (in my JUnit test), I was seeing the new responseText added to the previous calls response text (test failed).  The solution was to create a 'fresh' XmlHttp object for each and every API call; i.e. var XmlHttpRequest = new {...}.